# Incomplete svn commit histories with git svn

Tags: git, git-svn

We are migrating an svn branch to git.

We failed in getting a complete commit histories from svn in git repo and need help to get the complete history correctly.

git svn clone didnt work for us because it keeps failing with

"warning: There are too many unreachable loose objects; run 'git prune' to remove them."

Our repo has about r250000 commits

We have a repo root URL at https://abc.xyz.com/svn/app1

We have branch A containing folders (url: https://abc.xyz.com/svn/app1/proj1/A/trunk)

tp

src

jrp

We have branch B created (from Branch A at r12000) containing folders (url: https://abc.xyz.com/svn/app1/path/to/proj2/B/trunk)

tp

src

jrp

We want to migrate svn branch B to git as our trunk in git

We use non-standard SVN layout

We use git-svn version 2.18.0 (svn 1.7.14)

We do not use svn2git

What are we doing wrong ?

1st run

We tried

```
cd svngitTrunkrepo
git config gc.pruneExpire now
git config gc.auto 1
git svn init  https://abc.xyz.com/svn/app1 -T path/to/proj2/B/trunk --prefix svn/ svngitTrunkrepo
git svn fetch

error: invalid object 100644 xxxyyyzzz111222333444555666 for 'src/to/file.java'
fatal: git-write-tree: error building trees
write-tree: command returned error: 128
```

2nd run

We tried

```
cd svngitTrunkrepo2
git config gc.pruneExpire now
git config gc.worktreePruneExpire now
git config gc.reflogExpire now
git config gc.reflogExpireUnreachable now
git config gc.auto 1
git svn init https://abc.xyz.com/svn/app1 -T path/to/proj2/B/trunk --prefix svn/ svngitTrunkrepo2
git svn fetch -r 1:50000
git gc --aggressive
git svn fetch -r 50000:66813
git gc --aggressive
git svn fetch -r 66813:76813
git gc --aggressive
(continue)
git svn fetch -r 216813:220000
git gc --aggressive
```

The output of the run shows

```
(continue)
r218237 = b9e6e8ee272fdaa2611f6c3e9ccc05d412ecdf48 (refs/remotes/svn/trunk@218238)
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
Found branch parent: (refs/remotes/svn/trunk) b9e6e8ee272fdaa2611f6c3e9ccc05d412ecdf48
Following parent with do_switch
Successfully followed parent
r218239 = d4af17ac206cb4650f1aa0490dfdb4e1c00a5c16 (refs/remotes/svn/trunk)
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
Checking out files: 100% (63293/63293), done.
Checked out HEAD:
  https://abc.xyz.com/svn/app1/path/to/proj2/B/trunk r218239
fatal: gc is already running on machine 'ppplwxzdw' pid 21345 (use --force if not)
```

We then check the commit history

```
svngitTrunkrepo2]# git log -v
```

but we only saw 29 revisions as opposed to the expected 198312 revisions

Comment: Do you need to migrate commits back and forth between git and svn or are you just exporting from SVN? I recently tried git svn and failed as well. For an export only look into https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git

Comment: Hi  EncryptedWatermelon; thx for responding. We need to migrate commits back and forth between git and svn.

Answer (score 0):

The message

```
fatal: gc is already running on machine 'slc15zdw' pid 21345 (use --force if not)
```

indicates that `git gc` is trying to start twice. At the same time you have quite strange settings for `git gc` -- especially `git config gc.auto 1` means that for every loose object `git gc` will try to start. Which fits nicely to the above `fatal` message.

Try running `git svn` **without any** of the `gc.*` parameters - I think they will do more harm than good.